# SSIS adding unwanted additional spaces

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I was wondering if there are specific circumstances under which a data conversion task will force a column to be fixed length by adding spaces after the entry if it does not meet such length.

Fixed length columns for CSV import are not turned on.
I remove any spaces in the column via a derived column task.

Background: I'm attempting to process some postcodes but it seems as though the process is adding unwanted spaces. I've taken care of the situation where the input columns may have additional spaces by using a REPLACE(Postcode, " ", "") statement in a derived column. The data gets converted from Unicode to string (max length 7). Everything that isn't 7 characters when it gets converted seems to have spaces added after it. This isn't happening for exactly the same process used on phone numbers, however.

What's even more unusual is that this is a second version of a previous project, and I never had such an issue in the previous project! (with almost exactly the same process). It gets fixed if I perform the space removal after the conversion, but I don't want to have to run it twice over.

Comment: What is the SSISdatatype you are converting from & to?

Comment: @TabAlleman Unicode to string

Comment: Not the plain-english datatypes.   The SSIS datatypes.  DT_?

Comment: @TabAlleman DT_WSTR to DT_STR